# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^TA$ and $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a square matrix $A$, I was wondering what the condition(s) are for the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ to be the same as the eigenvalues of $A$.

Also what are the condition(s) for the eigenvectors of $A^TA$ to be the same as the eigenvectors of $A$. It seems that if $A$ is symmetric, then the eigenvectors of $A$ are the same as the eigenvectors of $A^TA$ (as $A^T=A$ so $A^TA=A^2$ and the eigenvectors of $A^2$ are the same as the eigenvectors of $A$), but what are the general condition(s)?

Can anyone please help as I can't find an answer to this?

Comment: It turns out (non-trivially) that $A^2$ and $A^TA$ have the same eigenvalues iff $A$ is symmetric

Comment: I am almost certain that they have the same eigenvectors iff $A^TA=AA^T$

Comment: @John thanks for pointing out my mistake, I meant to write eigenvectors throughout the whole of the second paragraph. I have edited my post now. Can you comment with my correction made?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks. How can I use these facts to establish the link between the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^TA$ and also for the link between the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^TA$?

Comment: I have nothing useful to say about the revised question (except that I suspect that @Omnomnomnom's conjecture is correct).

Comment: @Sami it turns out consequently that the two matrices will share eigenvalues iff $A$ is symmetric with all eigenvalues either $0$ or $\pm 1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for that but how would an eigenvalue of $-1$ work in this case? Wouldn't an eigenvalue of $-1$ give a corresponding eigenvalue of $1$ in $A^TA=A^2$ (as $A$ is symmetric)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom and John, Combining your answers brings me to the conclusion that $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $A^TA$ iff $A$ is symmetric and $A$ has eigenvalues of only $0$ and/or $1$ or, if complex, the $k$th roots of unity where $k$ is any prime. Just for clarity can you please confirm I've understood correctly? Regarding eigenvectors, $A^2$ and $A^TA$ have the same eigenvectors iff $A^TA=AA^T$, but when are the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^TA$ equal?

Comment: You're right, should be just $0$ and $1$

Comment: You're technically correct in your synthesis, but every symmetric matrix has only real eigenvalues.

Comment: If $AA^T=A^TA$, then there exists one common basis of eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^TA$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $A$ is a real matrix, using singular value decomposition we can write

$$ A = U S V^T$$

where $S$ is a real valued diagonal matrix (i.e., $S=S^T$); $U$ is the left Eigenvector and $V$ the right Eigenvector. Then, you can write 
$$A^TA = V S^T U^T  U S V^T = VS^2V^T$$.

However, if $A$ is positive symmetric, then $U=V$ and you can use eigenvalue decomposition instead of singular value decomposition. i.e., $A = USU^T$

Comment: To complete this answer: Since $S$ contains the eigenvalues of $A$ and $S^2$ contains those of $A^TA$, you need the squares of the diagonal entries of $S$ to be the diagonal entries of $S^2$, For this to happen, the modulus $|\lambda|$ of each eigenvalue must be $0$ or $1$. For modulus 1, there are lots of possibilities, including $\pm 1, \pm i$, but also things like the 3rd roots of unity (whose squares are the 3rd roots of unity) (or, indeed, the $k$th roots of unity where $k$ is any prime).

Comment: @MehdiXoylu thanks for your answer. Can you please confirm that a positive symmetric matrix is the same as a positive definite (or symmetric positive definite) matrix? I haven't come across this terminology before and am still learning linear algebra. I know $U$ and $V$ in the singular value decomposition as being the eigenvector matrices of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ respectively (with the eigenvectors normalised) and I haven't come across left and right eigenvectors before (I've only come across eigenvectors).

Comment: yes. please see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks but can you please explain how this works for $-1$ and for $\pm i$? Isn't it the case that their squares don't equal themselves? I must be missing something here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is it true that $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same eigenvectors **iff** $A^TA=AA^T$.